# Looking for the simplest way to unwrap root element for certain responses with FeignClient

Tags: kotlin, jackson, spring-cloud-feign, feign, data-class

I have a `FeignClient` which communicates with an external service, looks like below:

```kotlin
interface JiraClient {
    \\ ...

    @RequestMapping(method = [RequestMethod.GET], value = ["\${jira.api.agile}/sprint/{sprintId}/issue"])
    fun getIssuesForASprint(
        @PathVariable("sprintId") sprintId: Int,
        @RequestParam(name = "startAt", required = false) startAt: Int = 0,
        @RequestParam(name = "maxResults", required = false) maxResults: Int = MAX_RESULTS
    ): IssueHolder

    @RequestMapping(method = [RequestMethod.GET], value = ["\${jira.api.insight}/objectschema/list"])
    fun getObjectSchemaList(): List<ObjectSchema>
}
```

And here is my POJO:

```kotlin
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class ObjectSchema(
    @JsonProperty("id") val id: Int,
    @JsonProperty("name") val name: String?,
    @JsonProperty("objectSchemaKey") val objectSchemaKey: String?,
    @JsonProperty("status") val status: String?,
    @JsonProperty("created") @JsonFormat(
        shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,
        pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    ) val created: Date?,
    @JsonProperty("updated") @JsonFormat(
        shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,
        pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    ) val updated: Date?,
    @JsonProperty("objectCount") val objectCount: Int?,
    @JsonProperty("objectTypeCount") val objectTypeCount: Int?
)
```

It won't work because the response has an additional root element:

```json
{
    "objectschemas": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "APPS CATALOG",
            "objectSchemaKey": "AC",
            "status": "Ok",
            "created": "2020-01-01T11:11:11.000Z",
            "updated": "2020-01-01T11:11:11.000Z",
            "objectCount": 123,
            "objectTypeCount": 10
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "ORG CATALOG",
            "objectSchemaKey": "OC",
            "status": "Ok",
            "created": "2020-01-01T11:11:11.000Z",
            "updated": "2020-01-01T11:11:11.000Z",
            "objectCount": 456,
            "objectTypeCount": 20
        }
    ]
}
```

For the other responses, I have created holder data classes, because they have pagination info, that makes sense:

```json
{
    "expand": "schema,names",
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 200,
    "total": 1024,
    "issues": [
        ...
    ]
}
```

**Goal**:

I'd like to get it work, with an easy way to add some annotations (e.g.: `@ JsonRootName` ) to certain data classes (but not all), so that I can unwrap the root value `objectschemas` out of the box.  Please note, that the data class used here is only for deserialization purpose, I will not need it for serialization.  And I don't wanna add a bunch of logic into `fun feignDecoder(): Decoder`.  For the Feign Client interface, there is no chance to add any logic like `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE`.

Does anyone know the easiest way to achieve this?  Thank you very much.

The complete code snippets can be found [here](https://github.com/thyrlian/JIRA-Steward).